# Python, how to get substring between two known words

Tags: python, string

The text is like:

```
<CUSTOMER_ID COL_ID>="4000.01">79997/CUSTOMER_ID>

<CUSTOMER_ID COL_ID>="4000.01">799/CUSTOMER_ID>
```

I want to get the number of "79997" and "799"

how to do it in Python?

I am doing PySpark to process XML file

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have this format? So you're looking to grab the number between the first `>` and the second `<`?

Comment: That's not valid XML, by the way - I guess the `>` after `COL_ID` isn't really there, is it? Also, there's a `<` missing before `/`. @Cyber: Could it be that your edits are the cause?

Comment: the edits changed the format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) using a positive lookbehind assertion:

```
s  ='<CUSTOMER_ID COL_ID="4000.01">79997</CUSTOMER_ID><CUSTOMER_ID COL_ID="4000.01">799</CUSTOMER_ID>'
data = re.findall(r"(?<=>)(\d+)<",s)
print sum(map(int,data))
80796
```

Finds `d\+` one or more digits preceded by a `>` and followed by a `<`

Comment: It's really great! I runed as : re.findall(r"(?<=>)(\d+)<",x)[0], However, does it restrict how many digits? I calculate the max number of ID. The result is "999999". Actually it should be "1722342"

Comment: oh, I found the problem. My data actually is like "<CUSTOMER_ID COL_ID="4000.01">79997</CUSTOMER_ID>"

Answer (score 0):

If you're parsing XML, you should be using [an XML parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html).

For example, you can read a file like this

```
<root>
    <CUSTOMER_ID COL_ID="4000.01">79997</CUSTOMER_ID>
    <CUSTOMER_ID COL_ID="4000.01">799</CUSTOMER_ID> 
</root>
```

by using

```
import xml.dom.minidom
with open("test.xml") as f:
    doc=xml.dom.minidom.parse(f)
result = []
for item in doc.getElementsByTagName("CUSTOMER_ID"):
    result.append(item.firstChild.data)
```

which gives you

```
>>> result
['79997', '799']
```

Answer (score 0):

If the words are known you can use the string.replace() method:

```
s2 = s1.replace("foo1", "foo2")
```

Will replace all occurrences of "foo1" in s1 with "foo2" and store the result in s2.

For your particular scenario, you can replace the known words with blank strings and then cast the result to an integer:

```
#store string in s1
s1 = 'CUSTOMER_ID COL_ID="4000.01">79997</CUSTOMER_ID>'
#replace known strings with blank strings and cast result to integer, store value in s2
s2 = int(s1.replace('CUSTOMER_ID COL_ID="4000.01">', '').replace('</CUSTOMER_ID>', ''))
print s2

79997
```

I learned it's best to always use string methods when possible and to avoid diving into the re module unless necessary.